# Weird timezone issue with Tapku library

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nstimezone, tapku

I have a strange issue with Tapku Calendar control library.

It was showing me wrong date information, so I replaced all timezones from

[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]

to

[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

All works well till here.

However, when I changed timezone in the file called

NSDate + CalendarGrid.m,

at that point my calendar selection of dates was disabled.

No touches are being detected on calendar.

I have done all this step by step and found this issue in NSDate+CalendarGrid.m file.

I have already spent lot of hours finding this.

Please help in how to fix this weird issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is showing the wrong date information for the current month right? I mean the data which is displayed for the current month is wrong?

Comment: Yes. But I set timezone to systemTimeZone it shows correct dates, but touches are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the touches Disabled Problem, But for fixing the wrong date information problem, what you can do is change the following line in viewDidLoad

`[self.monthView selectDate:[NSDate date] month];`

to

`[self.monthView selectDate:[NSDate date]];`

Hope it helps

Comment: Same issue, this is not working for me. Although it gives correct date, touch remains disabled.

Comment: An update - touch detectable only on first row of calendar, not anywhere else. If I go to next month and come back to previous, then entire calendar is clickable. But not on first load.